# How to ask Clang++ not to cache function result during -O3 optimization?

Tags: clang, clang++

This is my code:

```
int foo(int x) {
  return x + 1; // I have more complex code here
}
int main() {
  int s = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
    s += foo(42);
  }
}
```

Without `-O3` this code works for a few minutes. With `-O3` it returns the same result in no time. Clang++, I believe, caches the value of `foo(42)` (it's a pure function) and doesn't call it a million times. How can I instruct it NOT to apply this particular optimization for this particular function call?

Comment: Move your function to another cpp? As long as you don't have link time optimization

Comment: GCC has `__attribute__((noipa))`.  Not sure if clang has it these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of curiosity, can you share why you would want to disable that optimization?

Anyway, about your question:

In your example code, `s` is never read after the loop, so the compiler would throw the whole loop away. So let's assume that `s` is used after the loop.

I'm not aware of any pragmas or compiler options to disable a particular optimization in a particular section of code.

Is changing the code an option?
To prevent that optimization in a portable manner, you can look for a creative way to compute the function call argument in a way such that the compiler is no longer able to treat the argument as constant. Of course the challenge here is to actually use a trick that does not rely on undefined behavior and that cannot be "outsmarted" by a newer compiler version.

See the commented example below.

- pro: you use a trick that uses only the language that you can apply selectively
- con: you get an additional memory access in every loop iteration; however, the access will be satisfied by your CPU cache most of the time

I verified the generated assembly for your particular example with `clang++ -O3 -S`. The compiler now generates your loop and no longer caches the result. However, the function gets inlined. If you want to prevent that as well, you can declare `foo` with `__attribute__((noinline))`, for example.

```c-like
int foo(int x) {
  return x + 1; // I have more complex code here
}

volatile int dummy = 0; // initialized to 0 and never changed

int main() {
  int s = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
    // Because of the volatile variable, the compiler is forced to assume
    // that the function call argument is different for each loop
    // iteration and it is no longer able to use a cached result.
    s += foo(42 + dummy);
  }
}
```